# Can't fix MSCONFIG Processor setting after changing number of processors to 8

Tags: windows-10, msconfig

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.
I was looking for ways to increase performance and I came across some postings on MSCONFIG.  I navigated to the option Boot/Advanced Options/Number of Processors.  When I checked it, I saw that I could change the number from 1 to 8.  I did so and rebooted.  Now, when I boot I get in an endless loop of Windows Automatic Repair telling me that I have a configuration error and "Attempting Repairs".  I'd like to change the Processors back from 8 to 1.
When I choose Advanced Options \ Troubleshoot \ Advanced Options I receive a menu of choices.

- Menu Options
- When I select "System Restore \Restore Point" for a few selections I get the message "System Restore did not complete successfully.  An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x800070003)"
- When I select "Go back to the previous version" I receive the message "We ran into a problem and won't be able to take you back to the previous version of Windows."
- When I select "System Image Recovery" I receive the message "Windows cannot find a system image on this computer."
- When I select "Start Repair" I get an error with that as well.

I've also taken the following steps already.

- Other Steps:
- Windows with Command Prompt (It Boots from drive  X", and the
  original drive "C" is now "E")
- net user administrator /active:yes
- CD E:\Windows\System32\config MSCONFIG  (I Receive the error: "You do
  not have sufficient privileges to run System Configuration.  Please
  run this utility as a user in the Administrators group."
- CD
  E:\Windows\System32\config ICACLS E:\Windows\System32\config*.*
  /INHERITANCE:r /GRANT:r Administrator:(F) /F /C
- Regedit
- (I point to
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
- File / Load Hive
- (I Navigate to)
  E:\Windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE
- Open
- (I receive the message
  "SOFTWARE You don't have permission to open this file.  Contact the
  file owner or an administrator to obtain permission")

How can I change the number of processor settings when I'm in Windows Automatic Repair?

Comment: What happens if you patiently wait for "Attempting Repairs" to complete or to announce failure?

Comment: I wait patiently (don't cancel or anything like that) and receive the message "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart.  We'll restart it for you".  It restarts automatically, then I get the Windows Automatic Repair screen with two buttons: Shut Down or Advanced Options.

Answer (score 2):

I kept looking and found a solution.  When in Windows Automatic Repair, I open the Command Prompt and type the following two commands:

1. `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} numproc`
2. `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} truncatememory`

Don't substitute anything for "{default}". That's how it's meant to be entered.
I rebooted and it fixed my problem.
I found this solution in the link: https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12554-how-to-fix-badsystemconfiginfo-error

Comment: saved my day, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

User3138025's answer worked for me after failing for hours with bootrec /fixmbr access denied, and other things also not working. I changed a bunch of msconfig settings including the number of cores (because it wasn't showing the right number in task manager), then couldn't get into windows. Solution: Had to CD command into c:windows/system32, then ran the above commands, fixed the stop errors. Now I'm back I'm trying to fix the wrong core issue shown in task manager. Thanks.

Comment: If you find another user's answer helpful you should upvote their answer.

Answer (score -2):

I went to MSCONFIG and chose the normal boot up option
That fixed mine when I restarted it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).